# shell script to find the nth occurrence of a string and print the line number

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a file named hello with the following data

```
onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
threechicken
twocows
```

I want to get the line number at which `chicken` is occurring for the second time.

Output should be `"4"` as `chicken` occurs for the second time in 4th line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk '/chicken/{++n; if (n==2) { print NR; exit}}' file

4
```

Answer (score 1):

shorter

```
$ awk '/chicken/ && ++n==2 {print NR}' file
```

if the input file is long, adding `exit` after printing will stop processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -n chicken hello| sed -n '2 s/:.*//p'
```

Answer (score 0):

for fun, using pattern as separtor and counting on field

```
awk -F 'chicken' 'NF>1{if (2==++o)print NR}' YourFile
```

using sed (not appropriate compare to awk) [`^J` is CTRL+V+J, real new line]

```
sed -e '/chicken/H;g;s/\(\^J.*\)\{2\}//;t h' -e 'd' -e ':h' -e ' =;q' YourFile
```