# How to find the nth string's line number, print and store it into a variable in a makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I am trying to find the line number of the string "PERSON" in a large text file and store the result into a variable to modify it for later use. In bash the line of code works, however when in the makefile it shows no result.

My reference is from this. [shell script to find the nth occurrence of a string and print the line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162782/shell-script-to-find-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-and-print-the-line-number)

```
.ONESHELL:
FILENAME = list.txt
initial:
    @read choice
    awk '/PERSON/{++n; if (n==$$choice) {print NR} exit}}' $(FILENAME)
```

I expect the result to be the line number of the choice occurrence of PERSON but I get no result.

Comment: try `awk -v choice=$(choice)  '/PERSON/{++n; if (n==choice) {print NR} exit}}' $(FILENAME)`

Comment: Is `@read` some new fangled make keyword with which I am unfamiliar, or are you reading the variable `choice` in one subshell and then trying to reference it in another shell?  Try `@read choice ; \\`

Comment: I don't think that "in bash the line of code works", due to the single quotes around the awk command, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `read` to get data from Make's input seems like a terrible idea.  But if you're going to do that, you have to reference the variable in the same shell reads it.  That is:

```
FILENAME = list.txt
initial:
    @read choice; \
    awk '/PERSON/ && ++n == c {print NR; exit}' c="$$choice" $(FILENAME)
```

Comment: Just to expand on this (as I imagine OP is not aware) -- each line of a makefile recipe  runs in its own shell instance.   Variables defined in the first shell instance are not visible in the second shell instance.   The `\\` joins the two lines, so they run in the same shell (and the variable is visible in both)

Comment: [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell) should run recipes in the same shell, but it requires make 3.82 or newer, IIRC.

Comment: It looks like the value of Choice is set into C but I wanted the Line number stored into a variable. Unless I'm overlooking something, where is and how can I use the line number?

Comment: Is this a question about make or the shell?  Storing the output of a program in a variable is easily done with `v=$(cmd)`.  Translating that into make is typically simply a matter of properly escaping the `$`.